# Attemp to invoke interface method java.lang.String com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap etc on a null object reference

Tags: image, firebase, url, react-native, storage

I'm getting this error after uploading image to firebase storage. I am using
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
"firebase": "^5.0.4",

this is my code for uploading the image.

```
// Prepare Blob support
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;

const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;

uploadImage = (uri, imageName, mime = "image/jpg") => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadUri =
        Platform.OS === "ios" ? uri.replace("file://", "") : uri;
      let uploadBlob = null;
      const imageRef = db
        .storage()
        .ref("images/")
        .child(imageName);

  fs.readFile(uploadUri, "base64")
    .then(data => {
      return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
    })
    .then(blob => {
      uploadBlob = blob;
      alert("blob is " + JSON.stringify(blob));
      return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
    })
    .then(() => {
      uploadBlob.close();
      return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    })
    .then(url => {
      resolve(url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    });
});};
```

Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference readAsText     FileReaderModule.java:43 invoke     Method.java invoke     JavaMethodWrapper.java:372 invoke     JavaModuleWrapper.java:160 run     NativeRunnable.java handleCallback     Handler.java:790 dispatchMessage     Handler.java:99 dispatchMessage     MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29 loop     Looper.java:164 run     MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192 run     Thread.java:764

Comment: same issue. did you find solution?

Comment: Not yet. Still trying to find out.

Comment: any solution yet??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same error. The solution is to do a 'Fetch replacement' as the official documentation explains:

> Since we are not implementing FileReader polyfill, you might run into
>   this error in some cases.
>
> If you're facing this problem with Blob polyfill in Debug Mode, try
>   replace window.fetch with fetch replacement should fix it.

And:

> If you have existing code that uses whatwg-fetch, now you don't have
>   to change existing code after 0.9.0, just use fetch replacement. The
>   difference between Official fetch and fetch replacement is that,
>   official fetch uses WHATWG-fetch js library which wraps XMLHttpRequest
>   polyfill under the hood, and our implementation simply wraps
>   RNFetchBlob.fetch.

Basically, you just have to add this to your code, just below your `window.Blob = Blob;` line:

```
const Fetch = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Fetch
// replace built-in fetch
window.fetch = new Fetch({
    // enable this option so that the response data conversion handled automatically
    auto : true,
    // when receiving response data, the module will match its Content-Type header
    // with strings in this array. If it contains any one of string in this array, 
    // the response body will be considered as binary data and the data will be stored
    // in file system instead of in memory.
    // By default, it only store response data to file system when Content-Type 
    // contains string `application/octet`.
    binaryContentTypes : [
        'image/',
        'video/',
        'audio/',
        'foo/',
    ]
}).build()
```

Documentation:
https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#failed-to-execute-readastext-on-filereader

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same problem. It has something to do with the prep statements:

```
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;
```

The error does not occur if I comment them out.

Comment: I don't think it will work because you haven't initialize the Blob variable

Which is needed in building blob object

fs.readFile(uploadUri, "base64") .then(data => { return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` }); })

Comment: What does the window.XMLHttpRequest do? The error seems to be triggered on that statement. I don't see the error occur if I comment it out.

Comment: Agreed its down to these prep statements.....did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by removing all this package because error still appearing even with fetch replacement I think Is triggered by
**window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;**
so I have used the old fashion

```js
const uriToBlob = (uri) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject(new Error('uriToBlob failed'));
        };
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', uri, true);

        xhr.send(null);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes it will work but in the case of file size >100Mb then it is not working