# How can i do a query get (params) with axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

i have to do this query, i tested in postman, it work very well, but in my app with react native, it does not work

https://api.rank.io/v1/currencies?api_key=861bec030719d86620078f861a5dfe7aa&symbols=BTC,ETH

this is my query

```
const params = {api_key:'861bec030719d86620078f861a5dfe7aa', symbols}
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.rank.io/v1/currencies', {params})
```

i am getting this error

attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.string com.facebook.react.bridge

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing ?

Comment: don't pass params as a key to a new object. Just pass params in the second argument of the axio.get method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807498/attemp-to-invoke-interface-method-java-lang-string-com-facebook-react-bridge-rea

Comment: can you create your answer please

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters along with the query:

```
const api_key = '861bec030719d86620078f861a5dfe7aa';
const symbols = 'BTC,ETH';

const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.rank.io/v1/currencies?api_key=${api_key}&symbols=${symbols}`)
```